# Self Hosted Webfonts - Fonts dont get correct loaded

Tags: css, sass, webfonts, google-webfonts

Its the first time i need to selfhost fonts because the new GDPR. I only used before google fonts. For the fontgeneration i used [google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/roboto?subsets=latin)

In my case i use Roboto 400 and 500 and get 4 files:

```
src/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-500.woff
src/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-500.woff2
src/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-regular.woff
src/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-regular.woff2
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
/* roboto-regular - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'),
    url('/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
    url('/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}

/* roboto-500 - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'),
    url('/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
    url('/assets/fonts/roboto-v18-latin-500.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
```

My Problem now is, that chrome (maybe all browsers) loads only the roboto 500 font file... But why? The Default Font is setted to 400. Only heading tags are using `font-weight: 500;`

Comment: It's because you override font-family, You have to set 2 differents name, one for Roboto 400 and one for Roboto 500.

Comment: But i want to use global Roboto and set with font-weight the font i need... Like with google Font API. This isnt possible without using google fonts?

Comment: You can leave the font-face code whit the same font-family name, but when you want to use a font-weight you must define like this: h1{ font-family: 'Roboto';font-weight:400} [article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/)

Comment: This is no option for me... How google do this when i use google fonts api? they inject javascript that handle this?

Comment: Read the article in my previous comments it may help you

Comment: What the article describe is exact that what i tryed. but in latest chrome it get only the roboto-v18-latin-500.woff from the server. But if there is no other option than to load every time the font family in each element I need then I will have to do that. Wondering how google does it, can not recognize a javascript file that solves it. Also strange is the google-font-helper code out there that does not work.

Comment: Google font's works exactly like the article describe

Comment: I got it now. the problem was that i got the font local installed on my windows machine... Thats why he dont get the font from the server. :P Everything is correct with my code.

Comment: :) :) Perfect :)